# Partitions with maximal length

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose $L$ is a non-empty finite set of positive integers, and let $d=\max L$.
For a positive integer $n$, define an $L$-*partition* of $n$ to be any sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$ of elements of $L$ such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_m=n$, and define $m$ to be the *length* of such an $L$-partition. Clearly, if $n$ has an $L$-partition, then there will be one of maximal length. Assuming that $n$ has an $L$-partition, I would like to have an upper bound on the number of $L$-partitions of maximal length, ideally as a simple function of $d$. As basic example, if $1\in L$, then clearly there is only one partition of maximal length for any positive integer $n$, $1+1+\cdots+1=n$ (with $n$ 1's). A less trivial example is
$L=\lbrace 5,6,7,8\rbrace $, $n=24$. Then $5+5+6+8$, $5+5+7+7$, $5+6+6+7$ and $6+6+6+6$ all have maximal length.

Comment: I don't think $d = \text{max } L$ can be enough to give a useful upper bound on the maximal length of an $L$-partition: In your $n = 24$ example, $L = \{1,8\}$ gives maximal length 24 while $L = \{8\}$ gives maximal length 3 while both have $d = 8$.

Comment: I am actually looking for a bound on the number of partitions of maximal length, not on the maximal length. If $L$ contains $1$ there is only one such partition, the one with all $1's$, but in my $n=24$ example, there are $3$. I wonder if $d=\max(L)$ is an upper bound?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now.  Have you gotten anywhere close to $d$?  For $\{5,6,7,8\}$, up to $n = 500$, the highest number of maximal length partitions is 4, which already occurs at $n = 24$ (the three you mention along with $5+6+6+7$).  For $L = \{6,7,8,9,10\}$ over the same $n$, the max is 6 (which first occurs at $n = 35$).

Comment: @Brian Hopkins No, I have not made any progress on this problem. There are formulas to find the number of partitions of $n$ into a fixed number of parts (chosen from $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots,n\rbrace$), but restricting the parts to be in a subset $L$ makes this very difficult. It's interesting there are so few partitions of maximal length up to $n=500$

Comment: This makes me think of questions around the Frobenius problem (e.g., the largest amount that you cannot make with summands 6 and 7 is 29) where you can also say something about the number of different sums when there are solutions.  If the connection is meaningful, it bodes badly for your problem, since even with 3 possible summands the Frobenius problem is very hard.

Comment: Yes, that is also known as the "postage stamp problem" and it is quite difficult. Unless there is some specially simple structure on the set $L$, I don't think one can expect any useful general results.